# Integrate Cashfree payment Gateway in Nextjs

Tags: php, reactjs, next.js, payment-gateway, cashfree

We are using Cashfree payment gateway and want to integrate it in our frontend which we developed using nextjs.  As per the documentation provided by cashfree(Most of the documentation is related to web Integration using PHP) we need to have a form with POST request which redirects to payment gateway on same window

```
<form id="redirectForm" method="post" action="https://test.cashfree.com/billpay/checkout/post/submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="appId" value="<YOUR_APPID_HERE>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="order00001"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderAmount" value="100"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderCurrency" value="INR"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderNote" value="test"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerName" value="John Doe"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerEmail" value="Johndoe@test.com"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerPhone" value="9999999999"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="<RETURN_URL>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="notifyUrl" value="<NOTIFY_URL>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<GENERATED_SIGNATURE>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentSplits" value="<payment_split_value>"/>
  </form>
```

In our code we are trying to make same request using Fetch

```
export const rtiPayment =(details)=>{
    var postData = [];
    for (var property in details) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    postData.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}
    return fetch("https://test.cashfree.com/billpay/checkout/post/submit",{
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'cache-control' : 'no-cache',
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          
        body: postData,
        json: true
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
      console.log(response)  
      return response
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

But we get below in response.

```
PaymentRti.js:42 Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
```

can someone suggest if we are making the request correctly. if not can you suggest the right way.

Comment: What were you expecting to get in the response object?

Comment: redirected: true and url: <Redirection Url>

Comment: or atleast the error(if any)